# Cantor's later life

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, cantor

I saw this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor#Later_years_and_death):

> In June 1917, he entered a sanatorium for the last time and continually wrote to his wife asking to be allowed to go home. Georg Cantor had a fatal heart attack on January 6, 1918, in the sanatorium where he had spent the last year of his life.

What happened to Cantor and his wife? Was his mental condition so bad that his wife wanted him to stay there?

Comment: Various biographical publications mention that Cantor suffered from manic depression (the modern term is bipolar disorder), which had manifested itself as early as 1884, and got worse after his youngest son died in 1899. The cause of death was heart failure.

Comment: It is treatable now, but not then.

Comment: See also https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Cantor/ which gives more details about the time course of his later struggles with depression.

Comment: @njuffa I was mainly wondering about their relationship, since the wiki article reads like Cantor was being treated there involuntarily.

Comment: See Dauben's [Cantor biography](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Georg_Cantor/8m3dDwAAQBAJ), page 284.

Comment: See also Ivor Grattan-Guinness, [Towards a biography of Georg Cantor (1971)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00033797100203837), page 368.